# Comparison define in C++

Tags: c++

Got a problem when reviewing other's code in C++. 
He defines a comparison as the following code:

```
auto f = [](const pair<Tweet*, Tweet*>& x, const pair<Tweet*, Tweet*>& y) {
        return x.second->time < y.second->time;
};
```

The environment is the follow:(`h` is defined as `vector<pair<Tweet*, Tweet*>> h;`)

```
make_heap(h.begin(), h.end(), f);
```

My question:

1. What is the '[ ]' means here?
2. I trying to rewrite as follow but does not work properly, what do I miss?

   ```
   bool f(const pair<Tweet*, Tweet*>& x, const pair<Tweet*, Tweet*>& y)
   {
     return x.second->time < y.second->time;
   }
   ```

Comment: Read about [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: What doesn't work properly? There's no error, nor an actual [mcve] that we can refer to. If I had to guess, I would say that the error is something like *function definition is not allowed here*.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: thanks, I will read through.

Comment: @chris: the comparison does not return the correct output. I will edit my answer and add the sample idea